# != "TEXT" not working Google Sheet scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script trying to identify if "HRZ" is found in Column F18:F, but it doesn't seem to work... It never identifies "HRZ" even if that is all thats in the column... Anyone able to help?

```
function exportNotifyHinges() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Hinge'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('F18:F'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var shouldExport = true;
  for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if ( testvalue[i] != "HRZ") {
      var response = ui.alert("Vertical conformance data identified in report. \n\n Do you want to cancel the export?",ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
      Logger.log(response);
        
      if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast("Export Cancelled...");
        shouldExport = false;
        }
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please share a view only copy of your sheet.

Comment: What do you see if you log `testvalue[i]` to the console? Do you see a string? Or maybe something else - such as an array of data `[ ... ]`?

Comment: It's in the ExportHinges.gs
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G6xLca7K9Tmvo0Kf2HxwnZUnLccF5ldP435rB1DPZ0s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Side note: I would also recommend using `===` and `!==` in preference to `==` and `!=` - [background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).

Comment: @andrewjames 7:31:57 AM Info [HRZ]

Comment: OK - you are trying to compare an array containing a string to a string. Just as a test, try: `testvalue[i][0] !== "HRZ"`. Consider that a range of cells is typically a 2-dimensional array - and when you use `testvalue[i], that reduces it to a 1-dimensional array.

Comment: its the same result...

Comment: And you do want them to be _not_ equal, right? In which case there is no logic to be performed...?

Comment: I want it to bring up the ui.alert if there is a value in F18:F that is NOT "HRZ"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to use the debugger and inspect the array testvalues

[image]

This reveals each element is a 2 dimensional array, so change this line of code

```
if ( testvalue[i] != "HRZ") {
```

to this and it works fine

```
if ( testvalue[i][0] != "HRZ") {
```

Comment: You are welcome! I have banged my head against the wall many times for simple mistakes. I always use the debugger and set breakpoints so I can make sure my scripts are doing what I expect them to be doing.

Comment: I would also recommend using `===` and `!==` in preference to `==` and `!=` - [background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons).